# How can i alter a more than one table in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I can alter the first table but i can't posibbly figure out how to alter the other one? Making them different names (table1, table2) doesn't work (don't mind the language).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <style>

    body {background-color: burlywood;}

    h1 { color: beige; text-align: center; font-size: 400% }

    img { display: block; margin: auto; width: 60%; border: 8px solid brown }

    h2 { color: beige; text-align: center; font-size: 200% }
```

I am able to mess around with the first table with this part of code

```
    table.center { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}

    table { font-size: 150%; padding-bottom: 120px }
```

.

```
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kavarna</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="kava_zgoraj.jpg" alt="kava" />
    <h1>IME KAVARNE</h1>
    <h2>Najboljša kava v mestu že od 1987!</h2>
<table class="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Dobrodošli!</th>
        <th>O nas</th>
    </tr>
        <td>Kavarna je vaš najboljši sosed, kadarkoli,<br /> vsak dan. Zjutraj se nam pridružite ob posebnih <br /> mešanicah kave in oragnskemu zajtrku <br /> ter sokovih, zvečer pa se zabavajte <br /> ob živi glasbi in koktejlih ter veliko več!</td>
        <td>Smo mala, družinska kavarna katere <br />lastništvo se prenaša iz roda v rod. <br />Ustanovljena leta 1987!</td>          
</table>
```

But i can't figure out how to work on this table too.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><strong>Kje nas najdete?</strong></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

.

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you not able to give the other `table` element a specific class you can target in the way you can with `table.center`?

Comment: Also, please avoid using of tables for layout.

Comment: Ohhh of course i can. Thank you!

Comment: Why should i avoid it?

Comment: @AlemKalender https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html. Using tables for layout is also not semantically correct as of html 4, and they are inflexible and harder to change layout later.

Answer (score 1):

Add separate CSS classes for this tables. Don't style by HTML tags.

Comment: Not necessarily true, it's usually best with the CSS Cascade to style all tables the same until you have a special case, then add a class to capture that special case.